# How to put array information in class

Tags: c#, arrays, class, for-loop

I have tried to do this, and read from internet how to use classes, but I still don't know, how do I define separate classes for customer and flight information?

---

I made a program that reads the information of customers and their flights from the standard input device, and allows searching flight and customer information. When a flight information is searched the application should print the information for all of the customers on that flight. When a customer information is searched, the application should print the information of customer's flight too.

I need to define separate classes for the customer and the flight information. The customer's class should contain name, id and flight id. The class should also define the constructor and a method which returns the customer's and his/her flight's info.

The flight class should contain id, origin, destination and date. As well as the constructor and a method which returns the flight information if the correct flight id is passed to it.

Hint: you need to define arrays of customer and flight objects to make the application work in a meaningful way.

```
string username;
Console.Write("Customer or Flight ? c= Customer  f= Flight ");
username = Console.ReadLine();

string[] array = new string[5];

Console.WriteLine("");
array[0] = "Customer";
array[1] = "Name";
array[2] = "Id";
array[3] = "Flight Id";

string[] flight = new string[6];
flight[0] = "Flight";
flight[1] = "Id";
flight[2] = "Origin";
flight[3] = "Destination";
flight[4] = "Date";

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{        
    if (username =="c")
    {
        string c = array[i];
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
    else if(username =="f")
    {
        string f = flight[i];
        Console.WriteLine(f);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

sorry i'm new with c#, and I have done the rest, and I just need that part.

Comment: Where is your attempt at creating a class? It's not in the code you're showing

Comment: i'm using visual studio and i need to create new class from file new...i tried but dont know how, i mean dont know how to put array information inside that and use it in main ...

Comment: When you're stuck on basic tasks like adding a new `class` then you should probably take a step back and look into some beginner C# tutorials first. Maybe have a look at the following MSDN page: [C# Tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx); Or take a look at the following tutorial: [Introduction to C# classes](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/introduction/)

Comment: there wasnt, info to how put array inside class

Comment: In the links I provided there is the information on how to add classes, how members are added to those classes and how to use these members. These are very basic programming concepts which you need to understand, if someone just provides a solution to you it is not going to help since you'll be stuck again very soon. But once you've understood these concepts the task of *"adding an array to a class and using it"* gets very easy. So (IMHO): Do not try to search for a finished solution you can copy, but rather try to understand the underlying concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone that you should take a couple hours and read a book or watch some examples on pluralsight or something. But here is some code to get you started.

Create a new Console C# project in visual studio. Click your project in the solution explorer, right-click it and go to add, add two C# class files to your project.

FlightInformation.cs:

```
public class FlightInformation
{
    public FlightInformation()
    {
        Passengers = new List<Customers>();
    }

    public string Flight { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Origin { get; set; }

    public string Destination { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public List<Customers> Passengers { get; set; }
}
```

Customers.cs:

```
public class Customers
{
    public string Customer { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int FlightId { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your Program.cs start adding customers/flights, then wrtie the code for searching - i wont do that part for you, hopefully this gives you a start

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var John = new Customers
       {
           Name = "John",
           FlightId = 24
       };

       var Flight = new FlightInformation
       {
           Id = 24,
           Destination="Cyprus"
       };

       Flight.Passengers.Add(John);

       //Code to search for flights

       //code to search for passengers
    }
}
```